# When using `openjdk:11` or `openjdk:8` with the experimental flags for CGroups, is `-Xmx` still needed

Tags: java, docker

According to 
https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/openjdk/README.md#make-jvm-respect-cpu-and-ram-limits

It says that JDK11 already uses `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` by default

However, I am still getting an error `137` and I see an OOM killer and there's a lot of memory available (over 1GB) when I type in `free -h`

Is `-Xmx` still needed to prevent the OOM errors?

Answer (score 0):

These two parameters are for when your JVM is running inside a container (like a docker container). These parameters **limit** the use of resources (CPU and memory) inside a container.

Out of Memory (OOM) error occurs when you are creating more objects/instances than the available heap-size. The above two parameters **limit** the heap-size ... so if you create more, you will still OOM error.

These two parameters have nothing to do with Xmx and Xms options that limit the heap-size (max and min). Notice that JVM being a form of VM, you can specify (at least in theory) an Xmx larger than the available memory (container's or host's).

I hope this answer your question.